# Create List \ ArrayList from query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, pgadmin

Entity

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Immutable
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments")
public class ClientEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_dt")
    private LocalDate created_dt;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Integer amount;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "account")
    private String account;

    @Column(name = "external_id")
    private String external_id;

    @Column(name = "external_status")
    private String external_status;
}
```

Service

```
@Component
public class SchedulerService {

    @Autowired
    //private final AttachmentEmail attachmentEmail;
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT pp.id, pp.created_dt, au.username, ss.name, pp.amount,\n" +
            "REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Success') AS status, pp.account,\n" +
            "pp.external_id, COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'Indefined') AS external_status\n" +
            "FROM payments AS pp\n" +
            "INNER JOIN auth_user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id\n" +
            "INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id\n" +
            "WHERE pp.created_dt::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)::date\n" +
            "AND ss.name = 'SomeName' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS'";

private static final DateTimeFormatter date_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    private static final DateTimeFormatter time_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    public SchedulerService(AttachmentEmail attachmentEmail, JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        //this.attachmentEmail = attachmentEmail;
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
    public void sendMail() {
        String filename = "select.csv";
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename)) {

            writer.append("id|Data|Time|Initiator|Service|Amout|Payment Status|Props|Identifier|External status").append("\n");

            this.jdbc.query(QUERY, (ResultSet rs) -> writeLine(writer, rs));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private void writeLine(FileWriter writer, ResultSet rs) {
        try {
        LocalDateTime ldt = rs.getTimestamp("created_dt").toLocalDateTime();
        writer.append(String.valueOf(rs.getLong("id")));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(ldt.format(date_format));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(ldt.format(time_format));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(rs.getString("username"));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(rs.getString("name"));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(String.valueOf(rs.getBigDecimal("amount")));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(rs.getString("status"));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(rs.getString("props"));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(rs.getString("Identifier"));
        writer.append('|');
        writer.append(rs.getString("external_status"));
        writer.append('\n');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sending request data by mail, having previously formed this data in a csv file. However, for this data to be correct, I need to compare two queries from two databases with each other. In the example that I indicated above, there is only one request. The idea is that I would like to store my SELECT in a collection (List, ArrayList) and then I will compare these two objects with each other via Comparator. Can't find how I can convert the above SELECTs to List / ArrayList

Comment: @M. Deinum I used your hint and also wanted to convert QUERY to List. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To compare two result sets for equality, you can use set operations:

```
WITH q1 AS (/* first SELECT */),
     q2 AS (/* second SELECT */)
SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM q1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM q2)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM q2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM q1);
```

This tests if there are any rows in the first result set that are not in the second and vice versa. If neither is the case, the two result sets must be identical.

Comment: The fact is that I have requests from two databases and an error occurs when requesting. So I think SELECT needs to be converted to object and then objects are compared

Comment: Then that is not a database question at all, and you will have to compare the result sets in your client code.